# Populating an array from another array

Tags: ruby, arrays, populate

I would like to create an array with the first letter from each element, but I keep just getting the entire element - what am I doing wrong?

```
def each_group_by_first_letter
  self.each do |x| 
    first_letter = []
    first_letter = x[0, 1].to_s
  end

  x = ["abcd", "efgh", "able"]
  x.each_group_by_first_letter do |letter, words|
    printf("%s: %s\n", letter, words)
  end
```

Comment: First of all, you need another `end` here somewhere.  I deduce that you meant it to be before the line `x = ["abcd"....`

Comment: yes...i cut down the code to the relevant parts...there is another end in there...

Comment: Well, your each_group_by_first_letter isn't returning anything explicitly, so in this case it's just returning `self`.

Answer (score 8):

There are several problems with your code. Among them:

- You create an array called `first_letter`, but then overwrite it with a string on the next line instead of adding the string to it. (To add an item to an array you will usually use [`Array#push`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-push) or [`Array#<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C).)
- You don't return `first_letter`, which means you're implicitly returning the array itself (assuming that's what `self` is--because that's what [`Array#each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-each) returns).
- When you call `each_group_by_first_letter` you pass it a block (`do ...`) but your method doesn't take or use a block. You probably mean to call `each` on the result of `each_group_by_first_letter`.

Regardless, the Array class already has the tools you need--no need to define a new method for this.

```
x = [ 'abcd', 'efgh', 'able' ]

x.map {|word| word[0] }
# => [ 'a', 'e', 'a' ]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
x = ["abcd", "efgh", "able"]
y = x.map{|e| e[0]}          # keeps x intact
```

or

```
x = ["abcd", "efgh", "able"]
x.map!{|e| e[0]}             # modifies x

 => ["a", "e", "a"]
```